# How to expand series into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, expand

Suppose we have a dataframe like:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1,2,3], 
                     'tags': [['toto','tata','titi'],
                             ['one','two','three'],
                             ['he','she','us']]})
```

data

```
  num   tags
0   1   [toto, tata, titi]
1   2   [one, two, three]
2   3   [he, she, us]
```

I don't understand why data.tags.apply(pd.Series) can expand data.tags into its own dataframe

```
data.tags.apply(pd.Series)

    0      1        2
0   toto  tata   titi
1   one   two    three
2   he    she    us
```

and DataFrame can not!

```
data.tags.apply(pd.DataFrame) 

0           0
0  toto
1  tata
2  titi
1           0
0  one
1  two
2  three
2           0
0  he
1  she
2  us
Name: tags, dtype: object
```

How it's work?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `apply()` as going rowwise through column `tags` in this case. So applying `pd.Series` is going to make each list a "horizontal" series. Then since you have a "vertical" column of these "horizontal" series you are left with a single dataframe. Conversely, applying `pd.DataFrame` will make each list a "vertical" dataframe so a "vertical" column of "vertical" dataframes will give you a series of dataframes.

Hopefully thinking of it in terms of "horizontal" and "vertical" helps a bit with the intuition of what is happening.

Comment: Thank's for help. Yes ,thinking in this way it's little bit more clear